# Transform a named vector to a data.frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering how I could achieve my desired `output` below in BASE R?

```
input <- c(a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3, b_1 = 1, b_2 = 0)

output <- data.frame(a = 2:3, b = 1:0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `split` based on the substring of the `names` of 'input' and convert to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(split(unname(input), sub("_\\d+$", "", names(input))))
#  a b
#1 2 1
#2 3 0
```

---

Or using `unstack`

```
nm1 <- sub('_\\d+$', '', names(input))
unstack(input ~ nm1, data.frame(input, nm1))
```

---

Or another option is `matrix` construction if the 'a', 'b' have equal lengths

```
matrix(input, ncol = 2,  dimnames = list(NULL, 
        unique(substring(names(input), 1, 1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` can also take care of this automagically if you make your vector a `data.frame`. It will also separate the `_x` part out to a `time` variable in the output, so long as the variable names are always in the `name_x` pattern.

```
reshape(data.frame(t(input)), varying=TRUE, sep="_", direction="long")
#    time a b id
#1.1    1 2 1  1
#1.2    2 3 0  1
```